# Delete Persistent Object when app is Deleted in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, persistent-storage

I am using persistent object in blackberry to store config details specific to the app. Here is how I am implementing the class

```
public class Preferences implements Persistable
{
    private static  PersistentObject persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0x2759d6ff72264bdbL);
    private static Hashtable tbl = new Hashtable();

    public static void storeLoginToken(String token)
    {
        token = removeCharAt(token,0);
        token = removeCharAt(token,token.length()-1);
        tbl.put("token", token);
        persistentObject.setContents(tbl);
        persistentObject.commit();
    }

    public static String getLoginToken()
    {
        Hashtable tbl = (Hashtable)persistentObject.getContents();
        try
        {
            String token = tbl.get("token").toString();
            System.out.println("Token = "+token);
            return token;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

But if I uninstall/delete the app these stored values are not getting deleted. When I installs the app for next time the app is fetching the old stored values.

How can i do this properly in blackberry?
Thanks

Comment: After deleting your application sometimes device doesn't ask the restart; If you restart your device before installing the same application then problem should solved; "The persistant object not deleted" problems mostly occurs in Blackberry version 5.0 devices; which version you are using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a custom hashtable class like this

```java
package com.myapp.items;


import net.rim.device.api.util.Persistable;

import java.util.*;

public class MyAppHashtable extends Hashtable implements Persistable{

}
```

And change your code to

```java
public class Preferences
{
    private static  PersistentObject persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(0x2759d6ff72264bdbL);
    private static MyAppHashtable tbl = new MyAppHashtable ();

    public static void storeLoginToken(String token)
    {
        token = removeCharAt(token,0);
        token = removeCharAt(token,token.length()-1);
        tbl.put("token", token);
        persistentObject.setContents(tbl);
        persistentObject.commit();
    }

    public static String getLoginToken()
    {
        MyAppHashtable tbl = (MyAppHashtable )persistentObject.getContents();
        try
        {
            String token = tbl.get("token").toString();
            System.out.println("Token = "+token);
            return token;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

This is so that we adhere to the following info from RIM

**The BlackBerry persistence model**

When you use the BlackBerry persistence model, data is only deleted if the store contains data that belongs to the removed application.

For example, if an application stores an object with a package called `com.mycompany.application.storage` and no other application on the BlackBerry smartphone makes reference to the package, the persistent store and the removed application are deleted.

The same is true if the object is wrapped in a container such as a `Vector`. Even if only one of the elements of the `Vector` has a package name that is not used by other applications, the entire `Vector` is removed from the persistent store.

Note: If the application does not store any objects with an identifying package structure, (for example, an application that stores `java.util.Vector` or `javax.microedition.location.AddressInfo` objects), the application should create and use a class that extends `Vector` in order to identify that `Vector` belongs to the given application. When you store this `Vector`, which is identified uniquely by its package, you guarantee that the data is removed from the persistent store when the application is removed.

This [info is from here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Testing-and-Deployment/Handle-stored-data-when-removing-an-application/ta-p/444832)

Comment: THanks for your answer. I implemented it as you said. But MyAppHashtable tbl = (MyAppHashtable )persistentObject.getContents(); is throwing class cast exception. Any idea?

Comment: Yes thats because you are reading the old values which are saved as hashtable. Clear the persistent store. remove all the values and delete the store. and then retry . It should work.

Comment: If you can have a look on this as well please http://stackoverflow.com/q/9093706/623401 . it would be great.

Comment: @rfsk2010 . i really appriciated for this guide line . i go through your suggestion but when i delete app from simulator and again run, Preference do not delete and its give me previous stored value. ? what may be the mistake ? i must have to test that case in device ?