# Disabling Sleep Mode in Blackberry using Code

Tags: blackberry, java-me

How to prevent the app from going to sleep mode in blackberry using J2ME?

I have seen this suggestion to do a [Key Injection](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Prevent-BlackBerry-From-Going-Into-Sleep-Mode/td-p/234912) also read this [docs](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/native/beta/documentation/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/lifecycle_disable_automatic_standby.html) from Native SDK.

But I am not sure whether the second method works with J2ME.

How can I do this efficently in blackberry with J2ME?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be achieved ...
you can send keyBoard event to the device. For more information see this [Prevent BlackBerry From Going Into Sleep Mode](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Prevent-BlackBerry-From-Going-Into-Sleep-Mode/td-p/234912).

Answer (score 1):

About disabling sleep mode, you can read [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Prevent-the-Lock-screen-from-interrupting-your-application/ta-p/445094) article.

To solve this problem in blackberry I used code below:

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Backlight;
import net.rim.device.api.util.DateTimeUtilities;

int MAX_BACKLIGHT_TIMEOUT_SECS = 255;

....

Backlight.setTimeout(MAX_BACKLIGHT_TIMEOUT_SECS);
Timer timer_ = new Timer();

timer_.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        Backlight.enable(true);
    }
}, 
(MAX_BACKLIGHT_TIMEOUT_SECS - 1) * DateTimeUtilities.ONESECOND, 
(MAX_BACKLIGHT_TIMEOUT_SECS - 1) * DateTimeUtilities.ONESECOND);
```