# How to delete a folder when uninstalling a Blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, directory, uninstallation

In my Blackberry app I'm persisting data in a folder called "mydata" in the user folder in device memory. Is it somehow possible to delete this folder, when the user uninstalls my app?
As I'm switching to a database persistence soon, I want to ask the same question for DB persistence (allthough it is mainly the same, since both are stored in file system).

I only found this 
[Delete Persistent Object when app is Deleted in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034174/delete-persistent-object-when-app-is-deleted-in-blackberry)
But it is about persistent store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CodeModuleListener` which is a listener used to receive notifications regarding the addition, modification, or deletion of code modules on the device.

One way you could do it is to have another app which monitors when the app in question is being deleted. You can monitor it using CodeModuleListener. When it detects a deletion, it can delete the folders in the device memory.

This wouldnt work if the user deletes the monitoring app first.

Comment: Thanks. Good idea, but I can't use this in my case.